# Call to undefined method App\Console\Kernel::load() - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I downgraded my application from `5.5 to 5.4` and i am getting this error when i run `php artisan serve`

> > Call to undefined method App\Console\Kernel::load()  - Laravel 5.4

Looking at other solutions, i run `composer dump-autoload` to resolve this issue but the issue persist. Same error. I don't really know if this is caused by my packages in the composer.json file posted below

What could i do to resolve this now?

Thanks in advance

**Composer.Json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.8.*",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
        "guzzle/guzzle": "~3.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": " ~2.1.0",
        "pda/pheanstalk": "~2.0",
        "picqer/php-barcode-generator": "^0.2.0",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.12",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~8.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "~1.1",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~7.0",
        "symfony/thanks": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories",
            "app/commands",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: delete vendor folder and run composer install again

Comment: @AnarBayramov i just did ... same error

Comment: can you delete composer.lock too ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is you did not ensure you updated your code to be Laravel 5.4 compatible.

In the [`Kernel.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.5/app/Console/Kernel.php) boilerplate that comes with Laravel 5.5+ there's the line

```
$this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');
```

This command was added in 5.5 to automatically detect any commands in the app/Console/Commands directory.

In order to get this code to work in 5.4 you need to remove that line and register all your commands manually under the `protected $commands = [ ]` array in the same file.

The source code for `load` is in https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php#L196 if you want to try to adapt it and put it in your own `Kernel.php`

Answer (score 0):

Delete vendor folder and composer.lock file after run `composer install` command

Answer (score 0):

Go to your_project/app/Console/Kernel.php and remove line

> $this->load(**DIR**.'/Commands');

in commands() function

Comment: Or it is `__DIR__` ?